# Matplotlib Subplot Boxplot x tick labels not displaying

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I would like the x-axes for both boxplots to be set by the list of labels rather than the column names in the original dataframe. I've tried a lot of things but can't get it to work!

```
fig = plt.figure()
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=1, figure=fig, width_ratios=[1,3])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1])
ax1.title.set_text("Summary")
ax2.title.set_text("Individual PAs")
ssubset.boxplot(ax = ax1)
dsubset.boxplot(ax = ax2)
ax1.set_xticklabels=("A", "B", "C")
ax2.set_xticklabels=("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
plt.savefig('graphq.png')
```

Comment: It's `ax1.set_xticklabels(("A", "B", "C"))` instead of `ax1.set_xticklabels=("A", "B", "C")`. I think that qualifies as typo, so voting to close.

Comment: Voting to close too. Identically you can also use a list as `ax1.set_xticklabels(["A", "B", "C"])`

Comment: Those are not typos. They reflect not understanding. More helpful would be if you explained where and why it went wring.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(["A", "B", "C"])
ax2.set_xticklabels(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"])
```

What you should have done was call the *method* `set_xticklabels` with a collection of some sort, such as a `list`. The contents of that collection would become the new tick labels.

However, what you did was set the *attribute* to a `tuple`, which of course did nothing.

As an aside, for things such as tick labels, it is generally more idiomatic to use a `list` (as a collection of homogenous elements).